# Html button click doesn't submit form data

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, web

I 'm drowning in this matter for hours....my html form displays but when I fill user name and hit submit button,it does nt redirect to the servlet.but when I type the URL as this **http://localhost:201/Practices/FirstPath?userName=achini** ,changing the Html form method into "get"..it works well...plz help me

**this is my achHtml.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="FirstPath">
    <input type="text" name="userName"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit here"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**this is my servlet called First.java**

```
package com.achini.practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class First
 */
public class First extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String userName=request.getParameter("userName");
        out.println("Hello from the get method.!!!"+userName);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String userName=request.getParameter("userName");
        out.println("hello fom the post method"+userName);
    }

}
```

### this is web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Practices</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>First</display-name>
    <servlet-name>First</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.achini.practice.First</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>First</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FirstPath</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input type must be submmit not button. Something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="FirstPath">
    <input type="text" name="userName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit here"/> <!-- NOTE THE CHANGE HERE -->
</form>
```

Comment: but with an error...when I remain the post method in html file...it gives the correct statement.."hello from the post method ach[username I entered] "...but when I change the html file into "get", it still displays the same statement....'hello from the post method ###'

Comment: 1.Are yousure that your browser is not caching the old form?
2.If you are usint chrome press F12 for check if the request is sendinf the data as GET data.

Comment: mmm...actually I'm using eclipse..I think the browser it uses is internt xplorer..hw to check weather it caches the old form?

Comment: Right clic -> View Source Code